# Changed some setting in VS Code, Now My 1st Python code not working

Tags: python, settings

My code is not running in VS Code

```
print("Hello World")
```

is there any gap in my setting, below is my changed settings as of now

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

Comment: How are you sure that it's the editor that's creating your problem? The code you've posted cannot run, because you've misspelled `print`. In your code, the first letter is uppercase, which will not work.

Comment: Why is it not running? Are you getting an error? First of all `Print("Hello World")` would never run.

Comment: yes i tried after correction in my spellings but still it is not working after running in it changes line in output panel instead of giving output. i am having doubt on my interpreter/terminal settings.

Comment: i just saved my file and removed all my installed extension and re-run it. now it is working fine. Thanks both for attending my problem.